# Does setjmp literally save the state of the program?

Tags: c, memory, state, setjmp

So, if I were to malloc 500 bytes, then use `setjmp` to save the state, then free the 500 bytes, then `longjmp`, would I be able to access those 500 bytes? For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf buf;

struct str {
   char s[200];
   int a;
};

int main() {
    struct *str = (struct str *)malloc(sizeof(str));
    (*str).s = "the string";
    (*str).a = 31;
    setjmp(buf);
    printf("%s %d\n", (*str).s, (*str).a);
    free(str);
    longjmp(buf, 1);
    printf("%s %d\n", (*str).s, (*str).a);
    return 0;
}
```

What will be the output of the second `printf`? Also, what's the meaning of the second argument in `longjmp?` I saw some people use large integers as the second argument.

Comment: Nothing will be outputted because that wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 3):

> Does `setjmp` literally save the state of the program?

No, `setjmp()` saves some CPU register values as well as some context to allow the program to resume execution at the same place under a very strict set of conditions.

Note that you do not allocate enough memory for a `struct str`: you pass `sizeof(str)`, which is the size of the `str` pointer. You should write this instead:

```
    struct *str = malloc(sizeof(*str));
```

Futhermore, you cannot initialize `str->s` with an assignment, you should define the `str` member as a `const char *` instead of an array.

> So, if I were to malloc 500 bytes, then use `setjmp` to save the state, then free the 500 bytes, then `longjmp`, would I be able to access those 500 bytes?

No, your program has undefined behavior because the memory block allocated by `malloc` and pointed to by `str` has been freed, thus `str` must not be dereferenced any longer.

Note that the last 2 statements in the `main` function will never execute because `longjmp()` does not return, it makes the program resume execution at the place where `setjmp()` returns and it makes `setjmp` return the value of the second argument passed to `longjmp()` (and the value `1` if `0` is passed for this argument).

Here is a modified version for illustration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf buf;

struct str {
   const char *s;
   int a;
};

int main() {
    struct str *str = malloc(sizeof(*str));
    str->s = "the string";
    str->a = 31;
    int res = setjmp(buf);
    if (res == 0) {
        printf("res: %d, str: %p, s: %s, a: %d\n",
               res, (void *)str, str->s, str->a);
        free(str);
        str = NULL;
        printf("str: %p\n", (void *)str);
        longjmp(buf, 0);
    } else {
        printf("res: %d, str: %p\n", res, (void *)str);
        if (res < 10)
            longjmp(buf, res + 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output (compiled with optimisations):

```
res: 0, str: 0x7fe44de00000, s: the string, a: 31
str: 0x0
res: 1, str: 0x7fe44de00000
res: 2, str: 0x7fe44de00000
res: 3, str: 0x7fe44de00000
res: 4, str: 0x7fe44de00000
res: 5, str: 0x7fe44de00000
res: 6, str: 0x7fe44de00000
res: 7, str: 0x7fe44de00000
res: 8, str: 0x7fe44de00000
res: 9, str: 0x7fe44de00000
res: 10, str: 0x7fe44de00000
```

Output (compiled with `-O0`):

```
res: 0, str: 0x7ff4885000e0, s: the string, a: 31
str: 0x0
res: 1, str: 0x0
res: 2, str: 0x0
res: 3, str: 0x0
res: 4, str: 0x0
res: 5, str: 0x0
res: 6, str: 0x0
res: 7, str: 0x0
res: 8, str: 0x0
res: 9, str: 0x0
res: 10, str: 0x0
```

As you can see, what gets preserved by `setjmp()` is difficult to predict so this function must be used with extreme caution in circumstances where the programmer is well aware of the compiler behavior and only for very specific needs.

Comment: Typo: `res: %s` should be `res: %d` in the `else` path.

Answer (score 0):

It is vaguely specified what exactly gets stored by `setjmp`, the standard just says:

> The environment of a call to the `setjmp` macro consists of information
> sufficient for a call to the `longjmp` function to return execution to the correct block and invocation of that block, were it called recursively. It does not include the state of the floating-point status flags, of open files, or of any other component of the abstract machine.

In practice this likely means: program counter, stack pointer, registers involved in calling convention, fundamental condition code registers. It does *not* include the heap as it sorts below "any other component of the abstract machine", but also because common sense tells us that storing the whole heap on the stack is senseless.

As for your code example, it is gibberish pseudo code and it uses `setjmp` in undefined behavior ways - any code using that function must always check the result.

Generally, these functions are some of the worst spaghetti programming horrors ever designed and should only be used for debugging program flow purposes, never for production code.

Comment: Oh, so setjmp and longjmp should only be used for debugging?

Comment: @dfmaaa1 Yes, they should only be used for debugging or for campfire horror stories.

Comment: Will keep this in mind when telling someone a campfire horror story